# How to update mongodb record by its objectId?

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I have to update a record in mongodb collection,
So using terminal, i can do this with:

```
db.collection_name.update({"_id": ObjectId("562dbdc57d0175ee0f8b4569")}, {$set: {"status": "In-progress"}});
```

But i want it to do within my PHP code. 
**So how can i update a record with criteria ObjectId in PHP?**

```
public function updateStatus($status, $uuid) {

        global $logger, $warnings_payload;

        var_dump(array("_id" => $uuid));
        var_dump(array("status" => $status));

        $this-> mongo-> selectCollection('collection_name');
     try {
            $result = $this-> mongo -> update( array( '_id' => new MongoId($uuid)) , array($set => array("status" => $status)) );
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            var_dump($e);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Result of var_dump(array("_id" => $uuid));

```
array(1) {
  ["_id"]=>
  string(24) "562dbda57d01754e058b4567"
}
array(1) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(9) "Delivered"
}
```

And Exception occurred is:

```
object(MongoException)#44 (7) {
  ["message":protected]=>
  string(67) "zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?"
  ["string":"Exception":private]=>
  string(0) ""
```

Comment: So what is your `$uuid` variable? It should be the result of [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php). Also a bit of a misnomer here since it is not a UUID it's an ObjectID, which is something completely different.

Comment: $uuid is ObjectId, mongo represents ObjectId with uuid..
Can you give me an example for update record in mongodb in PHP,
Thanks,

Comment: Basically we would all appreciate if you updated your question to show exactly how you are instantiating that variable and where the data is coming from, as well as showing proof that the input matches something that exists. Either you are doing something wrong in code or in provided input, and your presently listed code does not provide that information. Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33342690/edit) link on your question to provide that information.